# add class to children - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html code:

```
<div class="rotation">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to add class to ul, i want to do it using jquery, because ul, li are generated without any class.
Let say ul tag need to be `<ul class="image_rotation">`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Read about jQuery's `addClass` method here.](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('.rotation ul').addClass('image_rotation');
```

The above code will add a class of `image_rotation` to every `ul` that is a descendant of any element with the class `rotation`.

If you want to target only `ul`s that are an *immediate child* of an element with a class of `rotation`, use the [child selector (`>`)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('.rotation > ul').addClass('image_rotation');
```

If you only want to do this on one `.rotation` element, you should give it an id and select it that way. For example:

```
$('#rotation ul');
```

and

```
<div id="rotation" class="rotation">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="..." alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than google. I wrote my question and after 30 sec i get an answer. Before that i was looking this for this in google for unleast 10 min. Very good answer btw.

Comment: @miszczu Thank you and yes, this site is amazingly helpful. A friendly tip: be careful asking questions like this one. We can upvote or downvote your question depending on how much research effort you have put in and how clear the question is. This question is very clear, but I did see earlier that you got a downvote (it looks like your back to 0 now). This was probably because you didn't how any research effort. Remember to show what you've tried so far and what documentation you've looked at. Sometimes, after doing that, you can answer the question for yourself! cheers

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest keeping it simple:

```
$('div.rotation ul').addClass('image_rotation');
```

Or, if you have multiple `ul` elements within the `div.rotation` element, you can specify the first `ul`:

```
$('div.rotation ul:first').addClass('image_rotation');
```

The last `ul`:

```
$('div.rotation ul:last').addClass('image_rotation');
```

Or a `ul` of arbitray zero-based index, for example the third `ul` (with an index of `2`):

```
$('div.rotation ul:eq(2)').addClass('image_rotation');
```

or:

```
$('div.rotation ul').eq(2).addClass('image_rotation');
```

Or an immediate child (so no `ul` elements nested in any other elements):

```
$('div.rotation > ul').addClass('image_rotation');
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).
- [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).
- [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

Answer (score 4):

all you need is to find the UL in the div and assign it your class.
you can see it in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXmr8/), but the code for your HTML is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul','div.rotation').each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass('image_rotation');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy, just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.rotation ul').addClass('image_rotation');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".rotation ul").attr("class","image_rotation");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rotation").children("ul").addClass( "MyClass");
```

Comment: `children` has a lower case c and you are missing the `$` or `jQuery` before `(".rotation")`